# Yii2 model::find() with default where conditions

Tags: yii2

Using Yii2 in the View...

```
Products::find()->asArray()->all()
```

returns all products as array.
I'm looking for a way to make it return all products WHERE id != 1
I want to have only one place do modify what "->all()" returns for every model. 
I know that `Product::find()->where('id != 1')->...` is possible, but I don't want to write and maintain it in more than one place.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**1)** You can simply override `find()` method in your model:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['<>', 'id', 1]);
}
```

Usage:

```
$products = Products::find()->all();
```

**2)** Use [scope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#scopes).

Create custom query class:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveQuery;

class ProductQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
    public function withoutFirst()
    {
        $this->andWhere(['<>', 'id', 1]);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Override `find()` method in your model:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Product extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @return ProductQuery
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new ProductQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$products = Products::find()->withoutFirst()->all();
```

I think using second method is more flexible, because it makes code more clear.

*Additional notes:*

- Hardcoded `id` is not good practice. Better replace it with equivalent condition.
- For this examples I used different way of specifying condition. See different ways of specifying condition in `where` statement in [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).

Comment: With the first example, using another `where()` elsewhere in your code - e.g. `Product::find()->where(['col' => $value])->all();` will overwrite your 'default' `where()` in the model. Is there a way around this, other than using the scope class in the second example?

Comment: @JamesG With `where()` already defined you need to use `andWhere()` / `orWhere()` in order to keep initial condition.