# yii2 add where condition model for every find

Tags: activerecord, model, find, yii2, multi-tenant

In Yii2 I am trying to change an ActiveRecord model so that every time the application runs a find(), or findAll() it will also add an extra where to the condition.

For example, the application calls find() method on the Stock model:

```
$UsersStockFound = Stock::Find()
->where(['stockActive' => 1]);
```

So, here is what I want to happen, I would like the model to add an extra condition before the users gets to see the results.
Let's just pretend I have the tenant ref already stored under $this->tenant 
So I want to add this to the above query, but seamlessly through the model.

```
->AddWhere(['tenantId' => $this->tenantId]);
```

So in other words the whole will be as if it was:

```
$UsersStockFound = Stock::Find()
->where(['stockActive' => 1]);
->AddWhere(['tenantId' => $this->tenant]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply override find() method in your model:

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['storeActive' => 1]);
}
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545910/yii2-modelfind-with-default-where-conditions)**

Comment: Will this also affect the FindAll or would I need to override that to?

Comment: @MarkJohnson. just add `all()` in query else you have to override `findAll()`. Because both are different methods.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @soju. Thanks. Found it [findAll() include find()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L109)

Comment: Having an issue, if I use Stock::Find()->All() it seems to ignore the ->where(['storeActive' => 1])

Comment: ok it's not Stock::Find()->All()  that was the issue, it was Stock::Find()->where(..some condition..)->All() 

reason is that the where was overwriting the andWhere I had in the find() override method.

So I changed it to Stock::Find()->andWhere(..some condition..)->All() 
and it all works. 

andWhere() seems to default to where() if there is no where already. So as a rule I'll use that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

None of above solutions worked for me..
if you are having 'where` usage, whatever overrides you do, find will not work..

I found my own solution as below which will overwrite all ORM calls.

```
class model extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function find()
    {
              
        return new CustomActiveRecordQuery(get_called_class());
    }

}
class CustomActiveRecordQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
    // ...
        public function prepare($builder)
    {
            $this->andWhere(['status' => 'Active']);
            return parent::prepare($builder);
    }
}
```