# how to reset default scope in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using default scope in my project and it works fine.

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['is_deleted' => 0]);
}
```

But now, I want to show all the deleted records in the report section.

How can I skip default scope for particular query only?

Comment: Possible duplicates of:-[Yii2 model::find() with default where conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545910/yii2-modelfind-with-default-where-conditions)

Comment: @AlivetoDie this seems to great solution to create method with some condition and called it in every query .... but my project already have multiple queries fired from multiple locations, i am looking for solution that i need to change only one query

Comment: You need  just a simple  Model::find()->all(); or your question si more complex  ..  ?  explain better  .. is not clear what do you mean

Comment: @scaisEdge i am working on old project which uses above code everywhere. Now i want to show list of all the product, doesn't matter they are deleted or not. if i fire query `Product::find()->all()` the above code automatically adds `is_deleted = 0` condition and i do not get expected result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that you're using fresh query (without any params or conditions), you need to create new `ActiveQuery` object for given model.

```
$query = Yii::createObject(ActiveQuery::className(), [Post::class]);
```

Or add a helper method in model itself:

```
public static function freshFind()
{
    return parent::find();
}
```

and use it instead of `Post::find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to clear or redefine your condition:

```
$model = Model::find()->where('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could  avoid the use of find()  ..using a findBySql

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM product';
$product= Product::findBySql($sql,)->all();
```

in this way you all the models of product  ..

and you could also use

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . Product::tableName() ;
```

for avoid explici table name for Products